# Is there any well-known NP-complete problem that I can reduce a 'node placement' problem to?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, reduce, np-complete, np

I have the following NP-complete problem:

Given:

- a set of locations in a N × N field,
- a set of m nodes, and
- a connectivity graph of the nodes (i.e. an undirected graph whose edges represent every pair of nodes in contact with each other), and
- contact range R (in the same length unit as the N × N field),

find a placement of the nodes in the field respecting the connectivity graph (i.e. place nodes such that any pair in contact is nearer than R and any pair not in contact is farther than R), or show that such placement does not exist.

Is the a well-known NP-complete problem that this problem can be reduced to?

(Also an optimization version of the problem can be considered, i.e. to find the most optimal placement)

Comment: Hm. You're the one who claims that your problem is NP-complete, so doesn't that mean that *you* have to have a proof that you can obtain any other NP problem from yours?

Comment: The "complete" part of NP-Complete means it can be reduced to another Np-Complete problem.  If you don't know that, then your problem is just "NP", not "NP-Complete".

Comment: @SoapBox - No: the "complete" part means that another NP-complete problem can be reduced to it, not conversely. (More precisely, it's NP-hardness; NP-complete is NP and NP-hard)

Comment: It looks NP-complete. It's a special case of subgraph isomorphism, when one of graphs is the N x N field, where edges are between nodes of distance < R, and the second graph is given. I think it might be even NP-hard for R=1 or 2, but to simplify proof would consider varying R.

Answer (score 0):

[Set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) sounds alot like this problem. In fact, it may be almost precisely this problem. Even better: it has an [approximation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) guaranteed to be within O(log n) of the optimal solution.